# update state of input type select when select input open or close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, state

I have a project with nextjs and type script. I have a custom select component that rendered a select input, I want when select input opened I showed a helperIcon (like ^) and when select component close I showed another helperIcon (like &). I write a boolean state and onClick event change my state But it is not currectly work. This event fired when select input open **and** close but I want this event fired when select input open **or** close In other word onOpenEvent and onCloseEvent in my select input.

this is my state and my function that changed state

```js
    const [isOpenInputSelect,setIsOpenInputSelect]= useState(false);
    const test= () => {
        setIsOpenInputSelect((prevState) => !prevState);
    }
    
      <Select name='birth-date'id='birth-date'onClick={test} 
         helperIcon={ isOpenInputSelect?<Icon name='arrow-bottom' />
                                       :<Icon name='arrow-top' /> }>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option selected={true} value="13">13</option>
       </Select>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me

Comment: Is `<Select>` a component you've made yourself, or is it from a library?

Comment: @EldarB. I created this component

Comment: @Poldark Can you please show us the code for your `Select` component?

Comment: i can't access that now.i only want a event for opening or closing select input.eg(when select input opened console.log('open') and when select input closed console.log('closed')) onClick event can't help me @juliomalves

Comment: Do you mean you also want `test` to run on the `select`'s `onChange` event?

Comment: no,consider this link. http://jsfiddle.net/FpfnM/50/       this code wrote in jquery and js.i want this in react js.in this code when input select open log something and when it closed log something else. @juliomalves

Comment: @Poldark we can't really help you without knowing what the `Select` component has. If it doesn't have any relevant events, you'll need to add them. If, however, the component does have events, we need to know what they are so that we can use them in our answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can simply achieve this by just negation of you current state
Some thing like

```
const [isOpenInputSelect,setIsOpenInputSelect]= useState(false);
    const test= () => {
        setIsOpenInputSelect(!this.state.isOpenInputSelect);
    }
```

Try this it work for you. Thanks